# Работа с многоуровневым хэшмап

Tags: kotlin, java-hashmap

```
class CollisionOfTanks(val Ob1:InterfaceIObject,
                       val Ob2:InterfaceIObject,
                       val map:HashMap<Int,HashMap<Int,HashMap<Int,Int>>>)

            val collision = map.getOrDefault(1 to hashMapOf(direction1 to hashMapOf(coordinates1[0] to coordinates1[1])), 42)
```

Выдаёт ошибку

> Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter K should be
>   mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected
>   type). Try to specify it explicitly.

Я пробовал указать тип так:

```
    val collision = map.getOrDefault<HashMap<Int,HashMap<Int,HashMap<Int,Int>>>, Int>(1 to hashMapOf(direction1 to hashMapOf(coordinates1[0] to coordinates1[1])), 42)
```

Но тогда оно пишет вообще

> No type arguments expected for fun getOrDefault
>   (key: Int,defaultValue: HashMap>): HashMap>

Как это исправить? Или заменить? Мне всего лишь надо узнать, есть ли значение по данному ключу

Answer (score 0):

```
val map: Map<Int, Map<Int, Map<Int, Int>>> = mapOf()
val result = map.get(10)?.get(20)?.get(30) ?: 42
assertEquals(42, result)
```

Если какого-либо ключа в цепочке не будет найдено, то вернется 42.